# how to store items from database inside an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
public partial class Piechart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private decimal total = 0; // course total
    private decimal registered = 0;
    private decimal regAttend = 0;
    private decimal nRegAttend = 0;
    private int regPer = 0;
    private int regToTotalPer = 0;
    private int nRegPer = 0;
    private int angle = 0;
    private int angle2 = 0;
    private int angle3 = 0;
    private int parTotal = 0;
    //const string G = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Grouping) from Attendance";
   // SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    //SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(G);


    private string[] Status = new string[2] { "Attend", "Didn't Attend" };
    private string[] Course = new string[] {//items from database};
```

I want to use a sql statement to call a list of items and store inside the above array. I am doing this as previously the items in the array were hardcoded. Now I want to retrieve it from the database, as whenever there is a new item, a new pie chart will be drawn automatically.

Comment: Which **items** of database you want to store into an array?

Comment: why store it in an array just store it as a List<> and capture the datarow

Comment: @Avd items are from the above select statement."//const string g..."

Comment: How are you hitting the database? Are you locked into something specific, such as ADO.Net, or can you use Entity Framework, etc?

Comment: @mtaza we are using "sql connection to call the database", as stated above. the database we are using is sql server. And i am also using ASP.net

Answer (score 1):

here's a way to do this with an [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

```
ArrayList Course = new ArrayList();
const string query = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Grouping) from Attendance";
const string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Course.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }
}

//Course.ToArray(); // <-- cast to string array object do use in the pie chart
```